# Calculate Used Storage space for RDS in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

How should i calculate used storage space for any RDS instance in AWS ?
I am using the following code but there is no other option to find out.

```
  DescribeDBInstancesRequest request = new DescribeDBInstancesRequest();
    DescribeDBInstancesResult result = rdsClient.describeDBInstances(request);
    List<DBInstance> list = result.getDBInstances();
   for(DBInstance instance : list){
       System.out.println(instance.getAllocatedStorage());
   }
```

Comment: Using SDK purely? Please also add the SDK language to the tags

Comment: yes using AWS java sdk if the option is available else any other way using java.

Comment: Seems like this is the only way.

Comment: This gives only the initially allocated space but not the current usage isnt it ?

Comment: You need to use the Cloudwatch API to get the "FreeStorageSpace" metric.  Sorry I don't do Java so no code example from me